# Excel Summing Time Issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this is a question that has been asked before, but no matter what I check or try, I cannot seem to get excel to work with me.

So I have a large spreadsheet filled with phone times. For some reason the program being used to collect those times uses a different format for the times, and it is preventing me from summing everything up.

Here's a quick example of just the times:

01:00:01
01:00:00
:59:54
:59:53

And a lot more like that. Due to the ':' at the beginning of the short times, I can't seem to get it to sum up with the longer times.

I attempted a few things suggested by others with this issue, but no luck. I tried changing the format to number, to time, using custom format [h]:mm:ss, /:mm:ss, but I always get either 0 or 12:00:00 AM as answers.

Is there any way to get excel to sum up all those times together accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to sum your time values without creating any extra columns:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(A1:A99),VALUE(0&A1:A99)))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: =SUM(IFERROR(1*TEXT(A1:A4, "hh:mm:ss"),1*("0"&A1:A4)))
Tried that, and it gave me the output of 01:00:01 (the value from A1)

Comment: @user5504808 Yes, but why complicate things?

Comment: You're right, I didn't use your exact formula, so I tried again.
=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(A1:A4),VALUE(0 & A1:A4)))
I received the #VALUE! error.

Comment: Did you confirm it with Control-Shift-Enter?

Comment: Oops, must have missed one of those when I did it the first time. That worked! Just have to convert the output to custom [h]:mm:ss and it counts correctly.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Where A1 contains your time value as a text string, this formula will convert it to an Excel readable time value that you can perform math on (`SUM`, etc):

```
=TIMEVALUE(IF(LEFT(A1,1)=":","0"&A1,TEXT(A1,"[H]:mm:SS")))
```

The default output will be a decimal, where a whole 1 represents 24:00:00, 0.5 = 12:00:00, 0.25 = 06:00:00, and so on. This in turn can be formatted back to a timestamp using Excel's built-in formatting options.

I would add a helper column to store the converted values and them SUM the ones you want. You can format the result as [H]:mm:SS to see the total time (this format is allowed to exceed 24 hours).

It would be possible to use array formulas as well to nest the `TIMEVALUE` conversion formula inside a `SUM` formula, but it's more complicated so I'll need some time to think about it...

**EDIT -** See @ExcelHero's answer for the better array option.

Comment: Your formula is difficult to use with mine, but I tried to insert into it: 
=TIMEVALUE(IF(LEFT(A1:A4,1)=":","0"&A1:A4,TEXT(A1:A4,"[H]:mm:SS")))
This gave me the #VALUE! error.

Comment: Yes, if you're using arrays instead of single cells then it would need to be entered as an array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(TIMEVALUE(IF(LEFT(A1:A4,1)=":","0"&A1:A4,TEXT(A1:A4,"[H]:mm:SS"))))`

Comment: TIMEVALUE() was the key for me when using formula for the time values being summed

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter:

```
=IFERROR(1*TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss"),1*("0"&A1))
```

Comment: I tried this one. 
=IFERROR(1*TEXT(A1:A4, "hh:mm:ss"),1*("0"&A1:A4))
Unfortunately it just gave me the output of 01:00:00 (the same value as A2 for some reason)